# Run a method in parallel inside another method in python

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying and failing to run the following computation in python. I have a class, let's call it `class Telescope`, which has some method, `compute_something(self, args)`. Inside the same class I have a method, `simulation`, which needs to call `compute_something` eight times with different arguments. Each of these runs is independent from each other, so I could just run them at the same time, in order to speed up time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Using the same code that was proposed in one of the answers. Basically I have some code like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


class Telescope:
    def __init__(self, num):
         self.num = num
    def compute_something(self, a, b, c):
         print('Start')
         res = self.num * a * b * c 
         print('Finish')
         return res

    def simulation(self):
        starmap_in = []
        #Populate starmap_in
        for i in range(5):
            starmap_in.append(list(range(i, i+3)))

        with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
            print(pool.starmap(self.compute_something, starmap_in)) 
x = Telescope(10)
x.simulation()
```

I have tried what was proposed in the first answer (using locks) and also trying to use multiprocessing it as if there was not any classes involved but this has not been successful, the program starts running but it hangs as if there was there forever.

This same thing happens with the proposed code, it would work for the first 5-6 times I run it, but after this I need to restart the kernel.

Running on Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your actual code, along with the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). The code should be a [mre] and both code and error text should be included as *formatted text* (using the `{}` button) within the question body itself. [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: The code is 700 lines long, dependent on other modules, which are around 3000 lines all of them together. 

It is not that I am getting an error, it is just that it is not paralellizing the code, but running it as if it was not parallelized.

Comment: Please read the links in my first comment. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: @BohmArahnmob this comment may be a bit late, because someone already closed your question and someone else already provided an answer. But you say it is hard to show your code because it is so long. You don't need to show all 3000 lines. You can define a method `compute_something` which simply sleeps for 5 seconds. Will that let you experiment with multiprocessing, with code minimal enough that you could post it here? Coming up with a minimal reproducible example is a reasonable request, and leads to much better help for questions like this. Good luck!

Comment: You should add if you are using Windows, or Linux as this will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the kernel hanging problem on Arch Linux version 5.18.12. Are you perhaps running on bsd?

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 with Jupyter notebook @drake14w

Comment: I added two lines in the function, which were: print('Start') and print ('Finish') (see the edited version) to check whether something was being parallelized or not.

Comment: Sorry for the triple comment but I have just tried running tha same code in another computer and I don't have the same issue. I am shocked right now!

Comment: It might work on the first computer if you put `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` as the first line after your `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: I have tried and the error persists. My laptop (the one where the error shows up) uses python 3.8.8, whereas the computer where it works has python 3.7.4 @drake

Comment: I tried running the code in an online editor and was able to replicate the issue. I solved by removing the `pool.close()` line. I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: I tried that as well, but the error persisted! At this point I think I'm happy to leave as it is, as I'd never run this problem in my personal laptop, but on the other computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the "Pool" class from the multiprocessing library

Here's some example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Telescope:
    def compute_something(self, a, b, c):
        return a * b * c #Do your computations here
    def simulation(self):
        #The input to starmap needs to be formatted like this: [[arg1 for first call, arg2 for first call, arg3 for first call], [arg1 for second call, arg2 for second call, arg3 for second call]]
        starmap_in = []
        #Populate starmap_in
        for i in range(5):
            starmap_in.append(list(range(i, i+3)))

        print(starmap_in)

        with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
            print(pool.starmap(self.compute_something, starmap_in)) #This is what calls the function 5 times in paralell

x = Telescope()

x.simulation()
```

However if you will be using the self variable in your function, doing it like this is a really bad idea. You need locks to do this if you want to access self.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def init_pool_processes(the_lock):
        #Initialize each process with a global variable lock.
        
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

class Telescope:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def compute_something(self, a, b, c):
        lock.acquire()
        res = self.num * a * b * c #Do your computations here
        lock.release()
        return res
    def simulation(self):

        lock = mp.Lock()

        #The input to starmap needs to be formatted like this: [[arg1 for first call, arg2 for first call, arg3 for first call], [arg1 for second call, arg2 for second call, arg3 for second call]]
        starmap_in = []
        #Populate starmap_in
        for i in range(5):
            starmap_in.append(list(range(i, i+3)))

        with mp.Pool(5, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:
            print(pool.starmap(self.compute_something, starmap_in)) #This is what calls the function 5 times in paralell

x = Telescope(10)

x.simulation()
```

Edit:
Quoted fron the python docs:

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process). ... one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using if **name** == '**main**':

This would make your code look like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Telescope:
    def compute_something(self, a, b, c):
        return a * b * c #Do your computations here
    def simulation(self):
        #The input to starmap needs to be formatted like this: [[arg1 for first call, arg2 for first call, arg3 for first call], [arg1 for second call, arg2 for second call, arg3 for second call]]
        starmap_in = []
        #Populate starmap_in
        for i in range(5):
            starmap_in.append(list(range(i, i+3)))

        print(starmap_in)

        with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
            print(pool.starmap(self.compute_something, starmap_in)) #This is what calls the function 5 times in paralell

if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = Telescope()

        x.simulation()
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried running the code and it works the first time I run it, but if I run a couple more times (something like 4-5 times) the process stays hanging and does not return anything. This is the same problem I was having with the code above.